# Mongodb regexMatch within Lookup

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have a patients collections that looks like this

```
[
  {
   _id: ObjectId(60f5a851e8b5d11111111),
   firstName:"test_1",
   lastName: "test_last_1"
  },
  {
   _id: ObjectId(60f5a851e8b5d11111112),
   firstName:"test_2",
   lastName: "test_last_2"
  },
]
```

and a messages collections that looks like this:

```
[
  {
   _id: ObjectId(60f5a851e8b5d22222222),
   body: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.",
   createdByPatient: null,
   createdByUser: ObjectId(60e888ac01198634444444)
  },
  {
   _id: ObjectId(60f5a851e8b5d22222223),
   body: "It's a great day",
   createdByPatient: ObjectId(60f5a851e8b5d11111111)
   createdByUser: null
  },
  {
   _id: ObjectId(60f5a851e8b5d22222224),
   body: "I'm a message",
   createdByPatient: ObjectId(60f5a851e8b5d11111111)"
   createdByUser: null
  },
]
```

I'd like to pull the patients that have messages which match a substring. For example, using the dummy data above  and given the substring "day", the desired result should look like this

Results:

```
[
  {
   _id: ObjectId(60f5a851e8b5d11111111),
   firstName:"test_1",
   lastName: "test_last_1",
   lastMessage: {
      _id: ObjectId(60f5a851e8b5d22222223),
       body: "It's a great day",
       createdByPatient: ObjectId(60f5a851e8b5d11111111)"
       createdByUser: null
    }
  },
]
```

This will likely be solved using an aggregation.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your expected result:

1. `$lookup` - `patients` collection (key: `_id`) join `messages` collection (key: `createdByPatient`) and match the regex with `$regexMatch` operator. And it outcomes the `messages` field with an array value.

Note:

<strike>1.1. If the `_id` in `patients` collection is `ObjectId` type, you need to cast the `createdByPatient` in `messages` collection as `ObjectId` via `$toObjectId`. (Since you didn't provide the correct ObjectId, I assume that the `_id` in `patients` collection is `string` type.</strike>

1.2. `option: i` in `$regexMatch` means searching the string with ignoring case-sensitive.

2. `$set` - Set `lastMessage` field with get the last element of `messages` array via `$arrayElemAt`.
3. `$unset` - Remove `messages` field from the documents.

```
db.patients.aggregate([
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "messages",
      let: {
        patientId: "$_id"
      },
      pipeline: [
        {
          $match: {
            $expr: {
              $and: [
                {
                  $eq: [
                    "$createdByPatient",
                    "$$patientId"
                  ]
                },
                {
                  $regexMatch: {
                    input: "$body",
                    regex: "day",
                    options: "i"
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      as: "messages"
    }
  },
  {
    $set: {
      lastMessage: {
        $arrayElemAt: [
          "$messages",
          -1
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $unset: "messages"
  }
])
```

[Sample Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Je5LHMMDaAp)

Comment: Hey, apologies about the confusion but the IDs are all ObjectId type, I've updated the question to reflect that.

Comment: How do I cast the createdByPatient in messages collection as ObjectId via $toObjectId?

Comment: Updated mongo playground https://mongoplayground.net/p/UJ38FWeUZsZ

Comment: Have read your sample data in the attached link. As both `_id` (in patients collection) and `createByPatient` (in messages collection) are both ObjectId, then you are directly compare. For the case I mentioned in the answer, it is for when the values are in different type, then you have to make sure both values are in same type before comparing.